# How to integrate QuickBooks Online to Asp.Net Application using V3?

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

1.How to programmatically connect with QuickBooks Online using .NET? We followed the below article but this needs manual intervention to connect.
http://ippdocs.intuit.com/0025_QuickBooksAPI/0010_Getting_Started/0020_Connect/0010_From_Within_Your_App/Test_the_In-App_Connect_Flow

Initially we developed the sample application using the code:
https://github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/IPP_Sample_Code/tree/master/QuickbooksAPI/DotNet/WebForms%20application

2.Which type of integration method we have to use Json or .NET SDK library? Most of the Json examples are code fragment only, Where we can download the sample application using Json with .NET

Answer (score 1):

You cannot connect to Quickbooks APIs without manual intervention as it is a part of the 3 legged OAUTH flow.

The .Net SDK supports XML and JSON. There is no separate JSON library. The sample app for Dotnet in v3 is not yet available. Please refer to the docs for generating the JSON requests.

https://developer.intuit.com

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create SaaS application and want to publish it in Appcenter then you need to implement OAuth flow which needs user's input for authorization. In the dev env, using the above sample app, you can get the OAuth tokens(consumer key, consumer secret, access key and access token) which you can use in your app to call all API endpoints.

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0150_ipp_.net_devkit_3.0/0002_synchronous_calls/0001_data_service_apis#Step_3:_Build_the_ServiceContext

FAQ - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0058_faq

.Net V3 Link - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0150_ipp_.net_devkit_3.0

But Intuit Quickbooks API(V2/V3) are only for SaaS app. If you want to create some custom solution for one company then you should use QBSDK.

Ref -https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0250_qb

Thanks